# Pleasure of woman at the end of relations (source in Chazal?)

Tags: sources-mekorot, women, sexuality

I heard that it says in chazal the woman only has pleasure at the end ("gamar bia") of tashmish (relations). Is there any source/citation for this?

Comment: I don't understand by your first sentence, "I heard that it says in chazal the woman only has pleasure at the end ("gamar bia") of tashmish (relations)." How would that work? Am I just misunderstanding what you're saying?

Comment: can you either define gamar bia or point to a source where the term is used?

Comment: @vulcandeathgrip, re "point to a source": that seems to be what the question is asking.

Comment: @msh210 I was understanding the question to be a source that the term used is related to a woman's pleasure. does that mean that is the only time that term is used?

Comment: @vulcandeathgrip, I have no idea.

Answer (score 5):

This question does have halachic consequences although not the ones originally written by the questionnaire

The gemoro in kiddushin has the question if during the act of bioh with A  a woman accepted kiddushim (although highly unlikely) from B. The gemoro says she is married to B and not A because A only wanted the kiddushin to be 'chal' at gmar bioh.
If she is now considered a 'zona b'rotson' with A who is not her husband and therefore must obtain a get from B and also perhaps be punished with death is beyond the scope of this answer.

The pnai yehosha says the gemoro could have also said the 'woman' only wants the kiddushin to be chal at gmar bioh. His proof elsewhere from a yerushalmi in Sotah chaper 4 I am not sure about. All the yerushalmi says is that the woman has rotson or pleasure at the end. This need not mean like the pnai yehshua says at gmar bioh but after a time although not at the beginning if she is forced.

There are four possibilities. They both want at the beginning then she would be married to A. They both want at the end. Then she would be married to B. If man wants at the end and the woman at the beginning again she would be married to B.
The problem is if the woman wants at the end and the man at the beginning. Does the woman have a say in the matter. In other words does it make a difference to her. On that the pnai yehoshua says, it would be at the end and she would be married to B. Since it does make a difference to her.

This fully answers your question if a woman has more pleasure at gmar bioh.
This was a difficult question to answer and took quite a bit of effort and contains my own chiddushim.

Comment: Where is the Yerushalmi exactly (which halacha or daf according to any print -- just note which one it is.)

Comment: @Yehoshua sota chapter 4 halacha 4

Answer (score 1):

I believe the  last Tosfos on Gittin 41a answers your question.

Comment: You mean "כי מיעקרא לאו לא מקיים עשה אלא בגמר ביאה דחזיא להתעבר"? How does that answer this?

Comment: What is your kavana with that tosfos (re-iterating what @DoubleAA pointed out.)

Comment: My response was to the original question and not to the revised and amended one where it has no relevance. In the original question the main question was if Mirzvas Oinah is accomplished in the end? To which this Tosfos sheds light. To sum up, by Aveirah it's accomplished in the beginning but for a mitzvah it's accomplished at the end. Duk Vetishkach.